# ¿Como obtener el valor de una operacion con localStorage?

Tags: local-storage

estoy tratando de hacer que al presionar comprar n veces en el 1er producto se multiplique con el precio del mismo , y que al ir a la pagina 2 (q me muestra lo que compre hasta el momento) me cambie el valor de la cantidad y del total,en el total me tira NaN y la cantidad queda en 0, por el momento hice esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    

     let contador = localStorage.getItem("contadorCarrito") || 0;
     let cantidadp1 = localStorage.getItem("cantp1") || 0;


     $(".reset-carrito").click(function(){

        $(".contador").text(0);
        localStorage.removeItem("contadorCarrito");
    })


    $(".comprar").click(function(){

      $(".contador").text(contador);

       localStorage.setItem("contadorCarrito", contador++);

    }) 

    $(".contador").text(localStorage.getItem("contadorCarrito"));

    
    


    $(".prod1").click(function(){


         localStorage.setItem("cantp1" , cantidadp1++);
         $(".cantp1").text(cantidadp1);
         localStorage.setItem("precio1",$(".precio-p1"));


    })


     $(".total-p1").text(  localStorage.getItem("precio1") * localStorage.getItem("cantp1") );


})
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    background: #000;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}


.agregar{

    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;

}

ul li a{
    
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

a{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}


nav{
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px;
}

.carrito{
    margin-left: 558px;
}

.carrito , .contador{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
}

.reset-carrito{

    color: #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
    

}





.productos{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: #000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.productos >div{

    background: #78288C;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 200px;
    color: #fff;
}

.comprar{

    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.comprar:hover{

    background: #fff;
    color: #000;

}


.resumen-compra{

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4 , 100px);
    grid-template-rows:  repeat(4 , 20px);
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0px; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;

}

.fila1{
    font-weight: bold;

}

.resumen-compra>input , .resumen-compra>div{

    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background: #78208C;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pages.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carrito.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page1.html">PAGE1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">PAGE2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">PAGE3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="carrito">carrito <p class="contador">0<p><span class="reset-carrito">X</span></div>
</header>
<br><br>
<section class="productos">

   <div>
    <p class="precio1">100</p>
    <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar prod1">
   </div>

  <div>
    <p class="precio2">300</p>
    <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar prod2">
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="precio3">500</p>
    <input type="submit"value="comprar" class="comprar prod3">
  </div>
 
  <div>
    <p class="precio4">800</p>
    <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar prod4">
  </div>

</section>

 </body>
</html>
<!--page2-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carrito.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pages.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page1.html">PAGE1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">PAGE2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">PAGE3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="carrito">carrito <p class="contador">0<p></div>
</header>

<div class="resumen-compra">

    <div class="fila1">PRODUCTO</div>
    <div class="fila1">CANTIDAD</div>
    <div class="fila1">PRECIO</div>
    <div class="fila1">TOTAL</div>

    <div>producto1</div>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="10" class="cantp1" value="0">
    <div class="precio-p1">100</div>
    <div class="total-p1"></div>

    <div>producto2</div>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="10" class="cantp2" value="0">
    <div class="precio-p2">300</div>
    <div class="total-p2"></div>

    <div>producto3</div>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="10" class="cantp3" value="0">
    <div class="precio-p3">500</div>
    <div class="total-p3"></div>

    <div>producto4</div>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="10" class="cantp4" value="0">
    <div class="precio-p4">800</div>
    <div class="total-p4"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás obteniendo mal el valor del precio de este elemento:

```
<p class="precio1">100</p>
```

En esta línea de tu código JS:

```
localStorage.setItem("precio1",$(".precio-p1"));
```

Primeramente, **la clase del elemento es `precio1`**, luego, en el código jQuery **tienes que usar `text()`** para obtener el valor `100`, pues en tu selector actual estás seleccionando todo el elemento que tendría la clase, no su contenido.

Debería corregirse haciendo esto:

```
localStorage.setItem("precio1",$(".precio1").text());
```

### Recomendación

Debo decir que usar clases para obtener valores no es seguro, las clases tienen un uso más orientado a agrupar elementos que deberían tener el mismo comportamiento, formato CSS, etc, significa que una misma clase puede indicarse en más de un elemento y eso sería problemático para tu caso. Sería mejor asignar un `id`  (que debe ser único)  y obtener el valor con el selector de id (`#`), algo así:

HTML:

```
<p id="precio1">100</p>
```

JS:

```
localStorage.setItem("precio1",$("#precio1").text());
```

Por ejemplo, dado que los precios están dentro de una clase `comprar`, tú podrías escuchar los clicks de todos los productos (imagina que hay mil productos o más)  con un bloque como este:

```
$(".comprar").click(function(){
    //Trabajar con cualquier elemento dentro de un contenedor
    //con la clase comprar, usando this para referirse al elemento
    //que fue clickeado
}
```

En lugar de tener mil bloques que harían lo mismo:

```
$(".prod1").click(function(){

$(".prod2").click(function(){

$(".prod9999").click(function(){

$(".prod99999999").click(function(){
     //uffff
```

### Ejemplo

Aquí hay un ejemplo muy simple en el cual, desde un mismo bloque basado en la clase `comprar` se escuchan los clicks de todos los botones `Comprar` así, no tienes que replicar los eventos  `.click` para todos.

```js
$(".comprar").click(function() {
  console.log(`Seleccionaste el producto con precio: ${$(this).prev("p").text()}`);
  console.log('Aquí puedes agrupar todas las operaciones de los productos, escuchando todos los clicks que ocurran en los botonos comprar');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="productos">

  <div>
    <p class="precio1">100</p>
    <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar prod1">
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="precio2">300</p>
    <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar prod2">
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="precio3">500</p>
    <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar prod3">
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="precio4">800</p>
    <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar prod4">
  </div>

</section>
```